# How to check whether the range numbers exist in another numbers list without using for loop?

Tags: c#, .net

I have range of numeric values.

I want check each number within a range is exists in another numerics list.

I am using for loop, but it slows down my Application.

```
public void ShowResults()
{
    // The StartNumber and EndNumber is changed depends 
    // upon my requirement, They are not fixed.  
    int StartNumber = 1 ; 
    int EndNumber = 1000000;

    string[] list =
    {
        "1", "equal", "3", "perhaps", "6", "10", "378", 
        "1937", "28936", "26543", "937" .........,
        "understood" "99993"};

    for(int i = StartNumber; i<= EndNumber;i++)
    {
        List<int> resultList = new List<int>();
        int index = Array.IndexOf(list,i.ToString());
        if(index >= 0)
        {
            resultList.Add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating `resultList` every time through your loop - the posted code will create *one million lists*, which is probably part of your performance problem.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: If your string list `list` is much shorter than `EndNumber` minus `StartNumber`, then you could also say `list.Where(str => { int n; bool ok = int.TryParse(str, out n); return ok && n >= StartNumber && n <= EndNumber; })` or similar.

Comment: Move the declaration of resultList outside the for loop to solve the slow performance issue

Answer (score 1):

You could use binary search to find elements of one array in another, it would require one of the arrays to be sorted (the one on which you perform binary search):

```
        string[] arr = new string[]{
                    "1", "equal", "3", "perhaps", "6", "10", "378", 
                    "1937", "28936", "26543", "937",
                    "understood", "99993"
        };

        // Create sorted array
        int[] firstMillionNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000).ToArray();

        // Parse out numbers only
        List<int> listINT = new List<int>();
        int num;
        foreach (string s in arr)
            if (int.TryParse(s, out num))
                listINT.Add(num);

        // Find elements of a list inside sorted array
        List<int> resultList = new List<int>();
        foreach(int num2 in listINT)
        {
            if (Array.BinarySearch(firstMillionNumbers, num2) >= 0)
                resultList.Add(num2);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(list.Intersect(resultList).Count == resultList.Count)
{

}
```

Comment: Important to note that this will still use a loop behind the scenes. It's slow because comparing a million values *is* slow.

Answer (score 0):

trying to answer it in terms of algorithm rather than in programming language ..

you are trying to use two for loops which are causing o(n^2) complexity slowing down the program. If you have a range to compare, why not to iterate your list and check each value with two simple ifs ? this will reduce complexity to o(n) isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much you can do with your first list, the one that goes from "1" to "1000000", since it's dynamically determined. But what about your second? If this list of string is constant, or at least generated once and early, you should use a `HashSet<string>` rather than a `string[]`. This will make lookups on it a lot faster:

```
// This will create an IEnumerable<string> with all numbers to search.
IEnumerable<string> stringsToFind = Enumerable.Range<int>(StartNumber, EndNumber-StartNumber).Select(number => number.ToString());

// This is all the strings in a HashSet. This should be done *beforehand*.
HashSet<string> strings = new HashSet<string>(new [] {  "1", "equal", "3", etc...};

// resultList contains all numbers (from stringToFind) that are in strings).
var resultList = strings.Intersect(stringsToFind);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have to similar collections (with the same type numeric or string). Than you should select smaller collection and adoptate it to second collection. In example below I assume that `list` collection will be smaller than collection with numbers.

I don't know will it be good or not solution.

```
var originalNumbers = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
string[] list =
    {
        "1", "equal", "3", "perhaps", "6", "10", "378",
        "1937", "28936", "26543", "937", "understood", "99993"
    };

IList<int> parsedNumbers = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    int temp;
    if(int.TryParse(item, out temp))
        parsedNumbers .Add(temp);

}

var result = parsedNumbers .Intersect(originalNUmbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, iterating over a large set of variables will always be slow. There's no real way around it other than indexing or sorting (e.g. in a tree, so you're able to skip large parts of it).

However, your example code is slowed down even more due to you recreating a new `List<int>` once every iteration (something you probably don't want to do, as your results won't make any sense that way).

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with the question.  Why would you create resultList a million times (and it will only have the last value)?  Why are you calling i.ToString a million times rather than filtering the small list to int?

OK I know you are going to say this is not the real problem.   And my response is that is the posted problem.   If you want realistic answers you need realistic questions.

```
int StartNumber = 1 ; 
int EndNumber = 1000000;

string[] list =
{
    "1", "equal", "3", "perhaps", "6", "10", "378", 
    "1937", "28936", "26543", "937" .........,
    "understood" "99993"};

List<int> resultList = new List<int>();
int intOut;
foreach(string li in list)
{
   if (int32.TryParse(li, out intOut))
   {
       if(intOut >= StartNumber && intOut <= EndNumber) resultList.Add(intOut));
   }
}
```